# Animations not stopping after view controller is dismissed using tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, catransaction

**The Problem**
I have two view controllers, both are contained within respective `UINavigationController`s and a single `UITabBarController`. On one of the view controllers I am creating a bubbles effect, where I draw bubbles on the screen and animate their positions. The problem occurs when I move to the other view controller using the tab bar, this causes the CPU to spike and remain at 100% and the bubbles to continue to animate.

**Code**
The code for the bubbles is encapsulated within a `UIView` subclass.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // spawn shapes
    for _ in 1 ... 10 { // spawn 75 shapes initially
      spawn()
    }
  }
```

The `drawRect` method repeatedly calls the `spawn` function to populate the view with bubbles.

```
fileprivate func spawn() {
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.opacity = 0.0

    // create an inital path at the starting position
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint.zero, radius: 1, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360 * (CGFloat.pi / 180), clockwise: true).cgPath
    shape.position = CGPoint.zero

    layer.addSublayer(shape)


    // add animation group
    CATransaction.begin()

    let radiusAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    radiusAnimation.fromValue = shape.path
    radiusAnimation.toValue = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360 * (CGFloat.pi / 180), clockwise: true).cgPath

    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { [unowned self] in

      // remove the shape
      shape.removeFromSuperlayer()
      shape.removeAllAnimations()

      // spawn a new shape
      self.spawn()
    }

    let movementAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    movementAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint.zero)
    movementAnimation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))


    let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    animationGroup.animations = [radiusAnimation, movementAnimation]
    animationGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animationGroup.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animationGroup.duration = 2.0

    shape.add(animationGroup, forKey: "bubble_spawn")

    CATransaction.commit()
  }
```

Within the `CATransaction` completion handler I remove the shape from the superview and create a new one. **The function call to `self.spawn()` seems to be the problem**

On `viewDidDisappear` of the containing view controller I call the following:

```
func removeAllAnimationsFromLayer() {

    layer.sublayers?.forEach({ (layer) in
      layer.removeAllAnimations()
      layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    })

    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(nil)
  }
```

**Attempts from answers**
I've tried to add the `removeAllAnimations` function to the `UITabBarControllerDelegate`

```
extension BaseViewController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {

  func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

    bubblesView.removeAllAnimationsFromLayer()
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you removed `self.spawn()` from `completionBlock` ?

Comment: The shapes stop re-spawning once their animations complete. If there are animations in progress with this line removed and the next view controller is pushed the issue does not occur

Comment: You can add a boolean flag checking to control whether to `spawn` or not. Just a thought :D

Comment: Thanks! That's actually my current, (hopefully) temporary solution. Although I'm hoping to find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Welcome! .. here you are animating & end of animation on `completion` block you calling animate start again, which means you are on a `recursion` with infinite loop, that's why its animating all the time, you just need to control and stop that animation!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723401/why-changing-of-tab-stoping-the-animation-in-ios-app

Comment: check above link it is repeated question

Comment: @JagveerSingh Can you show me how it is a repeated question? The solution to your question was to set the `removedOnCompletion` flag to `false`. In the code accompanying my question you can see that the flag is already being set to `false` and the problem persists.

Comment: yes sir you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is, that you only use one thread for all that stuff. Please play around with dispatching everything that affects your GUI to the main thread and maybe explicitly new `spawn` instances to other threads. See how that goes. Something like this:

```
fileprivate func spawn() {

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.opacity = 0.0

    // create an inital path at the starting position
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint.zero, radius: 1, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360 * (CGFloat.pi / 180), clockwise: true).cgPath
    shape.position = CGPoint.zero


    // create an inital path at the starting position
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: startingPosition, radius: startRadius, startAngle: BubbleConstants.StartingAngle, endAngle: BubbleConstants.EndAngle, clockwise: true).cgPath
    shape.position = startingPosition

    // set the fill color
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    layer.addSublayer(shape)

    shape.opacity = Float(opacity)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
        CATransaction.begin()
    }

    let radiusAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    radiusAnimation.fromValue = shape.path
    radiusAnimation.toValue = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: endRadius, startAngle: BubbleConstants.StartingAngle, endAngle: BubbleConstants.EndAngle, clockwise: true).cgPath


    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { [unowned self] in

            // remove the shape
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                shape.removeFromSuperlayer()
                shape.removeAllAnimations()
            }

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                // spawn a new shape
                self.spawn()
            }
        }
    }


    let movementAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    movementAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: startingPosition)
    movementAnimation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: destination)


    let animationGroup = CustomAnimationGroup()
    animationGroup.animations = [radiusAnimation, movementAnimation]
    animationGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animationGroup.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animationGroup.duration = duration

    shape.add(animationGroup, forKey: "bubble_spawn")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer, I have to admit I have not worked with most of what you have suggested before. I have tried to implement your suggestions as best I can while also translating into Swift 3.0 and unfortunately the issue persists. Although if you wouldn't mind having a quick check to ensure I have converted the threading code correctly I would be very thankful.  https://gist.github.com/ollie-eman/3eccd3e015a9774a31696772ef9df817

Comment: I adjusted my example for Swift 3. Dispatching is much more comfortable now. :)

Comment: @Ollie For the code you provided on github, I think DispatchQueue.main.sync won't help you, at least try to use DispatchQueue.main.async (async vs sync)

Comment: Forgot to mention that, yes please use async like in my example. And background thread dispatching is now as simple as `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {`.

Comment: You beauty! After surrounding `self.spawn()` with `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async` the CPU spike has been fixed when swapping between tabs.

Comment: Glad to hear it. :)

Comment: I removed the other stuff from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In a UITabBarController, the associated view controllers have a flat structure. i.e. The view controllers in each tab run independently.

Hence, `func removeAllAnimationsFromLayer()` must be added in the delegate method

`func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController)`

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately the issue persists. I've added my implementation of your answer to the bottom of my question. If I have implemented it incorrectly please shout